# Downloading Zip file using angular-js and django

Tags: django, angularjs

I am trying to download a Zip File from my Django views.But I am calling the views function from my angularjs service by post request.The view is returning a zip file but it is not being downloaded.
Can anyone please tell me what are the contents of the .success function in  my angularjs service such that the zip file will be downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked fine for me. I hope this helps you.

```
var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'api/cdr/downloads/',
        responseType:"arraybuffer",
        data: selected
      };

      $http(req)
        .success(function(data, status, headers){
          var arr = data;
          var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arr);
          var a = window.document.createElement('a');

          a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(
            new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/octet-stream' })
          );
          a.download = headers('filename');

          // Append anchor to body.
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.click();


          // Remove anchor from body
          document.body.removeChild(a);
        }
      ).error(function(){
        }
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted here didn't work for me. Here's what did end up working for me:

In your javascript:

```
      $http({
                url: "/serveZip",
                method: 'POST',
                responseType: 'arraybuffer'
            }).then(function success(response){
                    var a = document.createElement('a');
                    var blob = new Blob([response.data], {'type':"application/zip"});
                    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    a.download = "myZip.zip";
                    a.click();
                    });
```

In your views.py:

```
def serveZip(request):
    zipPath = "path/to/myZip.zip"
    servableZip = open(zipPath,'rb')
    response = HttpResponse(servableZip, content_type='application/zip') 
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="myZip.zip"'
    return response
```

That worked for me in chrome, haven't tried elsewhere but you can try application/octet-stream instead of application/zip if its not working in other browsers.